# ASP.net alert box using RegisterStartupScript, produce javascript code but with error

Tags: c#, asp.net, alert

I have this C# code in my class:

```
private static void error_message(Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseException salah)
    {
        Page executingPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        Type cstype = HttpContext.Current.GetType();

        // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
        ClientScriptManager cs = executingPage.ClientScript;

        // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, "PopupScript"))
        {
            String cstext = "alert('" + salah.Message + "');";
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "PopupScript", cstext, true);
        }
    }
```

which produce this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
alert('ua_services not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).
');//]]>
</script>
```

But the alert box doesn't show up, and Chrome logs an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL "

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `salah.Message` contains a CRLF. Trim it or escape it.

Or wrap `RegisterStartupScript` in a method that does it.

Comment: Thanks! I replace some parts of the code with this `String cstext = "alert('" + salah.Message.Replace("\n", "") + "');";`